# When doing a sample of a groupby in Python Panda, how to get an rounded up sample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Right now I am using this python code using `pandas` Library

```py
grouped = df.groupby('EmployeeID')
temp = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac= 0.1)
```

**Scenario 1**: If there are 15 rows for EmployeeID: 1, I will get 2 sample rows as a result.
(15 rows *10%)

**Scenario 2**: If there are 12 rows for employeeID 2, I will get 1 sample row. (12 rows * 10%)

**My question** is for scenerio 2, how do I round up so that I get 2 rows instead of 1 row

12 rows turns into a temporary 20 so that I can do 20 rows *10% = 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use `math.ceil` like so:

```py
from math import ceil

grouped = df.groupby('EmployeeID')
temp = grouped.apply(lambda g: g.sample(n=ceil(0.1 * len(g))))
```